# Removing preventDefault and stopPropagation in javascript

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks on an element, I need to prevent the default action and perform an additional action. So far I have:

```
document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

The problem is that after I perform the above action, I need to remove the `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` because none of the links (a href) are being triggered after this. How do I undo this after performing it? Please note that it is a pure JavaScript code and I'm not using any library like jQuery. So I can't use `.bind()` and `.unbind()`. Any idea on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replicate the behavior of `bind` and `unbind` using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`

```
function stopIt(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", stopIt);

// then later

document.body.removeEventListener("click", stopIt);
```

Note: IE <= 8 doesn't support `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, so you'll need to use `attachEvent` as mentioned here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind the event to the body, bind the event to the element you need to prevent:

```
document.getElementById('theTarget').onclick = function(e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, I'm afraid you cannot undo the `e.preventDefault();` . But by default, the handler function will be executed before performing the default action. So in your case, you just don't need the `e.preventDefault();` at all. And remember to attach the event listeners only to `<a>` tags

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
    aTags[i].onclick = function (e) {
       // just perform your action here, don't need e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for breaking or rollback the stopImmediatePropagation():

Do unbind

$("#mydiv").unbind();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar challenge by using setTimeOut.

I have a collapsable filter panel which, when collapsing/expanding has some transition running for 700ms. Before the transition is finished, another click done before 700ms elapsed caused some wrong layout issues.

I declare a global variable "disabledCollapse" in a default state "false" which allows the code to run once. The variable becomes "true" for 701ms and that disables the click function for that period until the transition is over.

```
let disabledCollapse = false

$('#collapse-filter-button').on("click", function(e) {

   if (disabledCollapse) {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
      return
   }

   disabledCollapse = true
   setTimeout(function() {
      disabledCollapse = false
   }, 701)

   // my other code

})
```